# Difference between on and where in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 queries.
Query 1

```
delete b from automation1 b 
join report r
on b.Account_Number_Name = r.Account_Number
where b.StatementDate = r.StatementDate and
b.Cost = r.Cost and
b.ActualStartDate = r.StartDate and
b.ActualEndDate = r.EndDate and
b.Use = r.TotalUse
;
```

Query2

```
delete b from automation1 b 
join report r
on b.Account_Number_Name = r.Account_Number and
b.StatementDate = r.StatementDate and
b.Cost = r.Cost and
b.ActualStartDate = r.StartDate and
b.ActualEndDate = r.EndDate and
b.Use = r.TotalUse
;
```

what is the difference between this queries

Comment: Not that I'm doubting you that you know your data, but how does this condition `b.Account_Number_Name = r.Account_Number` equate to true.

Comment: I haven't read up on exactly how joins/wheres work, but I would think the second query would be a little faster since it is comparing all of the necessary columns as it is joining records and the first query is grabbing all of the records with matching account numbers and then filtering that down to just what you want.